# shell split awk to array

Tags: shell, awk

Hello I try to split awk to a array. I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

vms_disks=( "${vms_disks[@]}" "$(virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}')" )
for disk in "${vms_disks[@]}"; do
  echo "upload $disk"
done
```

This script should get the drives of a virtual maschine `"$vm"` in a array `"${vms_disks[@]}"`. But this script fill the array `"${vms_disks[@]}"` with only one key. the output of echo should be:

```
upload disk1.raw
upload disk2.raw
...
```

(upload for each Disk)

but I get:

```
upload disk1.raw disk2.raw ...
```

(only one Upload for all Disks together)

How to get the array-keys from `"$(virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}')"`

how to do that?

Comment: Why not start with `vms_disks=( "$(printf 'hello\nworld\n')" )` or similar and try to get that working first before adding all the other complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, haven't tested it since lack of samples.

```
mapfile -t myarr < <(virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put double quotes around:

```
"$(virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}')"
```

You are preventing word splitting from occurring, which means that the contents of your array are a maximum of two elements (words).

If the array `vms_disks` is initially empty, then `"${vms_disks[@]}"` expands to nothing, so your array only has one element.

Assuming that the output of `"$(virsh domblklist $vm --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}'` only has spaces *between* the elements, then I think you can just remove the quotes and allow word splitting to happen:

```
vms_disks=( "${vms_disks[@]}" $(virsh domblklist "$vm" --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}') )
```

Don't forget that quotes *inside* the command substitution (e.g. around `$vm`) are still important!

Since you're already making the assumption that `virsh domblklist $vm --details` output only contains newlines between records, a slightly more robust way to do the same thing would be to use a loop to build the array:

```
vms_disks=()
while IFS= read -r disk; do
  vms_disks+=( "$disk" )
done < <(virsh domblklist "$vm" --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}')
```

A slightly shorter form to do the same thing would be to use `mapfile`/`readarray`:

```
virsh domblklist "$vm" --details | awk '/disk/{print $4}' | 
  mapfile -O ${#vms_disks[@]} -t vms_disks
```

I'm using `-O ${#vms_disks[@]}` to start writing to the end of the array `vms_disks`, in case it already exists and contains elements (this matches your attempt in the question).